# ExecuteCommand in data linq query

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I use ExecuteCommand in data context in linq to pass **update** command like this

```
_context.ExecuteCommand("update tb_ExpList set exp_name = '" & TextBox8.Text & "',exp_desc = '" & TextBox7.Text & "',exp_limit = '" & TextBox4.Text & "',exp_type = '" & TextBox3.Text & "' where Expl_id= '" & x.Expl_id & "'")
```

It works well and updates my database directly.
My question is:
how do reflect the new data that I updated on my textbox objects on vb.net form.

I used 'Refresh' like this, each line separately, but it doesn't work.*emphasized text*

```
_context.Refresh(Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues).

_context.Refresh(Data.Linq.RefreshMode.KeepChanges).     

_context.Refresh(Data.Linq.RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues)
```

Comment: I don't see why you're even using EF if you're going to save changes like that. You may as well just use ADO.NET.

Comment: Ever heard of *SQL injection*? You're wide open to it. BTW I removed the entity framework tag. EF is not the same as linq-to-sql.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I would expect no less when the text boxes are named like `TextBox8.Text`...